# How to create json object using json simple with "dot" in name?

Tags: java, json, json-simple

My json object looks like this

```
 {
 name.raw:John
 }
```

How would I create the corresponding json simple object "name.raw". I am facing issues due to the dot in name

Answer (score 1):

Name the variable name with a string

```
{'name.raw':'Jhon'}
```